# How to make a chart with multi histograms

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have some mess about making a chart with multy histograms in R (try to use ggplot2). The example of my need is generated in Excel chart (see link):

[image]

The initial dataset is below:

```
attribute   DEV_share   current_qty_share
1           0,04999641  0,115217086
2           0,050001729 0,076647464
3           0,04999641  0,074048054
4           0,050001729 0,071905297
5           0,049999069 0,067865674
6           0,049999069 0,059962063
7           0,049999069 0,054130954
8           0,049999069 0,052725868
9           0,049999069 0,047421666
10          0,049999069 0,036040466
11          0,049999069 0,033370802
12          0,049999069 0,029085289
13          0,049999069 0,027047913
14          0,04999641  0,034354363
15          0,050001729 0,036567374
16          0,049999069 0,039728818
17          0,049999069 0,042222847
18          0,049999069 0,036532247
19          0,049999069 0,02511592
20          0,050017684 0,040009836
```

For each attribute (#1,2,3...) correspond two variables ('DEV_share' - blue color and 'current_qty_share' - green, yellow, red colors.

Two dashed lines mean cut-offs: the first cut-off corresponds to the 17th attribute and second one - to the 10th attribute. 
Cutt-offs are landmarks to distinguish colors per attribute for 'current_qty_share' variable: 17-20 - green, 10-16 - yellow, 1-9 - red. The blue color is the same for all attributes of 'DEV_share'.

X-axis contains attribute values, Y-axis cintains values of 'DEV_share' and  'current_qty_share'.

It would be very grateful if you could make a hint ot example how to make a chart like in Excel template (see the link).

Comment: this http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/geom_bar.html should help you started; by the way it's not a histogram, but a bar graph that you have

Comment: @  MLavoie:

thanks for such a fast reply. 
I have looked at the link and wonder how to place my share value to Y-axis (in all examples only 'counts' are presented that the equivalent of frequency in histograms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is something to help you started. First, I had to replace all your "," by "." in your data frame. If you want to show both columns, you will need to convert your data frame from wide to long. I also added a way to color differently your bars, which you can change as you wish.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
data_wide <- read.table(text="
attribute   DEV_share   current_qty_share
1           0.04999641  0.115217086
2           0.050001729 0.076647464
3           0.04999641  0.074048054
4           0.050001729 0.071905297
5           0.049999069 0.067865674
6           0.049999069 0.059962063
7           0.049999069 0.054130954
8           0.049999069 0.052725868
9           0.049999069 0.047421666
10          0.049999069 0.036040466
11          0.049999069 0.033370802
12          0.049999069 0.029085289
13          0.049999069 0.027047913
14          0.04999641  0.034354363
15          0.050001729 0.036567374
16          0.049999069 0.039728818
17          0.049999069 0.042222847
18          0.049999069 0.036532247
19          0.049999069 0.02511592
20          0.050017684 0.040009836",
  header = TRUE)

data_long <- melt(data_wide, id.vars=c("attribute"))
data_long$Color <- 
  with(data_long,
       ifelse(variable == "current_qty_share", "darkblue", 
         ifelse(variable == "DEV_share" & attribute >=1 & attribute <8, 
                "darkred", 
                ifelse(variable == "DEV_share" & attribute >=8 & attribute <=17, 
                       "green",      
                       "yellow")))

ggplot(data=data_long, aes(x=as.factor(attribute), y=value, group=variable, fill=Color)) + 
geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') + 
theme_bw() + 
geom_vline(xintercept=10, linetype = "longdash") + 
geom_vline(xintercept=17, linetype = "longdash") + 
xlab("attribute") + 
ylab("value") + 
scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkblue", "darkred", "green", "yellow"))
```

[image]

Comment: @ MLavoie:
Thanks a lot. Your comment is really great! :-) It is beyond my belief :-)

Comment: @ Axeman:
thanks a lot for comment. Well, sometimes i did it but "," was not repalces with "." So I prefer to make replacement explicitly through Stringr package.

Comment: @Dimon, don't forget to accept the answer if this what you want!